# How can I store a website of a given link in case I lose wifi or internet connection?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, kiosk

I am working on a kiosk chrome app. This app shows a webpage in an iframe like this:

```
$("body").find("#webview").attr("src", "http://myslide.com/slide2")
```

How can I make sure the kiosk keeps running the slide even when it loses internet connection?

I have tried with html local store but it does not work. Also some slides come with many mp4 videos.

Comment: Try adding "**`offline_enabled`**" to your manifest and read about [Offline First](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps). Also, if you are loading a HTML5 page, make sure you've cached it to make it possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work. The app is being used with a chrome bit and not a simple browser. It behaves different and I do not find any help in the documentation for what I need to achieve.